# Make doesn't recognize changes in indirect dependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies, dependency-graph

Consider this simple makefile:

```
all: output.txt

# The actual build command won't be this simple.
# It'll more be like "some-compiler file1.txt",
# which includes file2.txt automatically.
output.txt: file1.txt
    cat file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt

file2.txt:
    echo "heyo" > file2.txt

file1.txt: file2.txt
```

On first run, Make recognizes that `file2.txt` is a dependency of `file1.txt`, and so it needs to be built for `output.txt` to be built. Thus, it runs `echo "heyo" > file2.txt` and then `cat file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt`.

However, on subsequent runs, **if `file2.txt` is changed, Make doesn't rebuild**! If `file1.txt` is changed it does, but not for `file2.txt`. It just gives the dreaded `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.` message.

One hacky solution I've seen people suggest is to do the following:

```
all: output.txt

output.txt: file1.txt file2.txt
    cat file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

However, that's not possible in my case, as my secondary dependencies (the lines like `file1.txt: file2.txt`) are dynamically generated using `include`.

How do I make sure Make checks for modifications **all the way up the tree** when I have **multiple levels of dependencies**?

Comment: Apparently, adding `touch file1.txt` after `file1.txt: file2.txt` makes this work. But... *why*? Why does it matter that you touch `file1.txt` when `file2.txt` has been modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your makefile is slightly *too* simple.

Let `a -> b` denote `a depends on b`.  From your makefile you have...

```
output.txt -> file1.txt -> file2.txt
```

When `make` tries to update `output.txt` it sees that `output.txt` depends on `file1.txt`.  It then notices that `file1.txt` depends on `file2.txt`. At that point the dependency chain stops.  If make sees that `file2.txt` is newer than `file1.txt` it will run the command(s) that is associated with the `file1.txt: file2.txt` delendency.  In this case, however, there aren't any commands -- just the dependency itself.  That's fine as things go, but it does mean that even if `file2.txt` is updated `file1.txt` won't be.  Hence, when make moves up the dependency chain to...

```
output.txt: file1.txt
```

it sees that `output.txt` is *still* newer than `file1.txt` so there is no need to run any command associated with that dependency.

If you add the `touch` command...

```
file1.txt: file2.txt
        touch $@
```

then `file1.txt` *will* be updated and so the dependency chain works as you expect.

Comment: Oh, so Make doesn't keep track of which targets it's built? It *only* goes by modification time?

Comment: It's not so much a case of "Make doesn't keep track of which targets it's built".  It's simply that, having run a command/recipe to rebuild a target, it doesn't then simply *assume* that the target was updated -- modification times will always be used when checking whether or not a target needs to be updated based on one or more of its dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile does **neither generate nor update** `file1.txt` at all (i.e.: `file1.txt` must exist at the moment of running `make`). It contains *no recipe* for generating `file1.txt` from `file2.txt`. It has just  an *empty rule* (i.e.: a *rule without recipe*):

```
file1.txt: file2.txt
```

Since `file1.txt` a prerequisite of `output.txt`, this empty rule just implies that `file2.txt` must exist for `output.txt` to be built, it does not even update `file1.txt` when `file2.txt` is generated.

Since `file1.txt` is the only prerequisite of `output.txt` and `file1.txt` is never updated by `make`, once `output.txt` is generated, it remains always up-to-date (provided `file1.txt` is not externally updated).

`file2.txt` being changed never causes `output.txt` to be rebuilt because:

- it is not a prerequisite of `output.txt`.
- it does not update `file1.txt` (which is the only prerequisite of `output.txt`).

---

#### Solution

Given your current `output.txt` rule:

```
output.txt: file1.txt
    cat file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

If you want `output.txt` to be built every time `file2.txt` changes, then you need `file1.txt` to be built every time `file2.txt` changes. This can be achieved by means of a rule whose *recipe* actually updates `file1.txt` and has `file2.txt` as prerequisite, e.g.:

```
file1.txt: file2.txt
    touch $@
```